# Autostart App for Android

Tags: android-app, auto-start

I am looking for an app for an Android tablet to `Autostart` an app, quickly.  The one I used to use is no longer compatible with Android 13.  I dont mind paying a small once off fee.

Comment: Related on Android.SE: [Open an app on startup/after booting](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98276/44325)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few and ended up using [Boot Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argonremote.launchonboot).

There is a 3 second delay between the tablet powering up and the required app starting.  I can live with that.  It is free and you can add multiple apps to start up.

Sample Screen

[image]